# Multiply an array by a number in Coldfusion

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

I need to multiple an array by a number (2) using Coldfusion.

For ex: myArray = [1,2,3,4]

multiply each element by a number 2

I know there is a map method to do so, but wasn't sure how it would work in Coldfusion.
Is there a function to do this? or will need to write a custom function/method for this?

Comment: 'multiply an array'? What does that even mean?

Comment: Also, with most questions it is good to include what you have already tried, and any error messages. Seeing the code can help clarify ambiguous questions.

Comment: multiply each element of an array

Comment: No there are no existing functions, afaik. You need to write your own, or for CF10 you might look into [closures](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d31851842acbba1353e848b35-7ffa.html). Side note, what method are you referring to here: *"I know there is a map method"*?

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion are you using? (pls retag question)

Comment: Not sure what the vote to close is all about here?

Comment: Someone must have voted to close the original version, before the OP clarified what they were asking.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see how the question first started out now. This just demonstrates what a poor system this "close the question if it's unclear" approach is. Better is to simply explain how the question needs clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to write your own function. It sounds like you might already have a handle on how to do that -- but, in case it's helpful, here's how I would implement it:

```
<cffunction name="ArrayMultiply" >
    <cfargument name="SourceArray" type="array" >
    <cfargument name="Factor" type="numeric" >
    <cfset NewArray = ArrayNew(1) >
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(ARGUMENTS.SourceArray)#" >
        <cfset NewArray[i] = ARGUMENTS.SourceArray[i] * ARGUMENTS.Factor >
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn NewArray >
</cffunction>

<cfset MyArray = ArrayNew(1) >
<cfset MyArray[1] = 1 >
<cfset MyArray[2] = 2 >
<cfset MyArray[3] = 3 >
<cfset MyArray[4] = 4 >

<cfset MultipliedArray = ArrayMultiply( MyArray, 2 ) >

<cfoutput>
    <p>[ #MultipliedArray[1]#, #MultipliedArray[2]#, #MultipliedArray[3]#, #MultipliedArray[4]# ]</p>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to do this!

Comment: Do not forget to localize all function local variables (array and loop index). Also, for CF8+, you can shortcut the creation of arrays by using `[]` or `MyArray  = [1,2,3,4]`

Answer (score 4):

With CFScript

```
<cfscript>
for(var item in myArray) 
    { 
    myArray[item] *= 2; 
    }
</cfscript>
```

OR if you want to keep the original

```
<cfscript>
newArray = myArray;   

for(var item in newArray) 
    { 
    newArray[item] *= 2; 
    }
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using ColdFusion 10, you can use [`arrayEach()`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/arrayeach):

```
<cfscript>
original = [1,2,3,4];
multiplied = [];
arrayEach(original, function(e){
    arrayAppend(multiplied, e * 2);
});

writeDump(var=[original, multiplied]);
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the map function doesn't exist in CF 10 or Railo 4, you could use the [map function](http://russplaysguitar.github.io/UnderscoreCF/#map) in the [Underscore.cfc library](http://russplaysguitar.github.io/UnderscoreCF/):

```
_ = new Underscore(); // init library

result = _.map([1, 2, 3, 4], function(val) {
   return val * 2;
});
```

Note: I wrote Underscore.cfc